# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when using contact chooser

Tags: c#, contacts, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to implant a contact chooser into my wp8 application but get the error `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` I'm using the exact code from http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/How-to-choose-a-Contact-and-get-Contact-details-in-a-WP7-app but it doesn't work for me...

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to add ID_CAP_CONTACTS to your WmAppManfiest.xml asking for the Contacts Permission?